# Get Unique values from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, list

I am trying to get unique values I can add to a select tag from my JSON.

My JSON:

```
[
{
    "active_subscribers": 11158,
    "date_x": "2018-11-21",
    "segment": "e077"
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11158,
    "date_x": "2018-11-21",
    "segment": "e099"
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11156,
    "date_x": "2018-11-22",
    "segment": "e079
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11156,
    "date_x": "2018-11-22",
    "segment": "e079"
}
]
```

I want to get unique `segment`

My expected result:

- e077
- e099
- e079

Comment: Lots and lots of similar questions on this site..what have you tried?

Comment: One dupe, looking for a more recent one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480391/get-unique-objects-from-array-based-on-single-attribute

Comment: Look into 'map' to get only the segment values, and then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop through each element and keep pushing them to an array after checking if element already exists in array or not.

Use `Array.forEach` to loop and `Array.indexOf` to check if element already exists in array or not.

```js
var x = [
{
    "active_subscribers": 11158,
    "date_x": "2018-11-21",
    "segment": "e077"
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11158,
    "date_x": "2018-11-21",
    "segment": "e099"
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11156,
    "date_x": "2018-11-22",
    "segment": "e079"
},
{
    "active_subscribers": 11156,
    "date_x": "2018-11-22",
    "segment": "e079"
}]


var unique = [];
x.forEach(function(e){
 if(unique.indexOf(e.segment) == -1){
  unique.push(e.segment);
 }
})

console.log(unique);
```